# Change wireless paramaters in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, wireless, intel, centrino

My laptop has windows 8 and i have a Intel Centrino N 2230 wireless adapter.

I had issues with connecting to Internet over WI-FI and in order to fix this,i changed the WI-FI adapter property to `802.11n channel width for band 2.4`

From then on,there have been no problems.Now,I have installed Ubunty 13.04 as a dual OS and WI-FI just does not work.I suspect this is because of the Ubuntu not taking the right adapter property.My iwconfig details are as follows:

```
$ iwconfig
eth0    no wireless extensions 
lo      no wireless extensions
wlan0   IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"NETGEAR"
Mode:Managed  Freequency:2.43t GHZ
```

Any idea how I can change that IEEE value to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try the following:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot. If your issue is fixed, there is no need to proceed further. If not, we'll remove the ineffective fix and try another:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Remove only the last line that we added: options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1. Proofread, save and close gedit. Now do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y" > /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot and see if your issue is resolved.